# Matplotlib stackbarchart cannot plot the next bar if bottom parameter is 0

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-chart

I am trying to plot stackbarcharts using matplotlib. Here is the scenario for the data.

**Matplotlib version 3.1.0**

```py
a = np.arange(len(b.iloc[0][4:]))
for ind,i in zip(a,a):
    print(
    b['Total B- %'].iloc[i],
    b['Total B %'].iloc[i],
    b['Total B+ %'].iloc[i],
    b['Total A- %'].iloc[i],
    b['Total A %'].iloc[i])
```

**Output:**

```py
0.0 35.714285714285715 0.0 28.57142857142857 35.714285714285715
0.0 50.0 0.0 31.25 18.75
0.0 0.0 6.25 15.625 75.0
0.0 0.0 7.4074074074074066 18.51851851851852 74.07407407407408
0.0 24.242424242424242 30.303030303030305 27.27272727272727 18.181818181818183
2.272727272727273 36.36363636363637 2.272727272727273 20.454545454545457 38.63636363636363
0.0 0.0 0.0 9.090909090909092 90.9090909090909
0.0 6.25 15.625 15.625 62.5
0.0 30.303030303030305 18.181818181818183 27.27272727272727 24.242424242424242
0.0 8.571428571428571 17.142857142857142 25.71428571428571 48.57142857142857
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 100.0
0.0 25.0 0.0 25.0 50.0
```

**My stack bar chart code is as follows:**

```
a = np.arange(len(b.iloc[0][4:]))
for ind,i in zip(a,a):
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total F %'].iloc[i], width, bottom=b['Total D- %'].iloc[i],color=palette(0),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total D- %'].iloc[i], width, bottom=b['Total D %'].iloc[i],color=palette(10),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total D %'].iloc[i], width, bottom=b['Total D+ %'].iloc[i],color=palette(25),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total D+ %'].iloc[i],width, bottom=b['Total C- %'].iloc[i],color=palette(50),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total C- %'].iloc[i],width, bottom=b['Total C %'].iloc[i],color=palette(75),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total C %'].iloc[i],width, bottom=b['Total C+ %'].iloc[i],color=palette(100),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total C+ %'].iloc[i],width, bottom=b['Total B- %'].iloc[i],color=palette(125),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total B- %'].iloc[i],width, bottom=b['Total B %'].iloc[i],color=palette(150),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total B %'].iloc[i],width, bottom=b['Total B+ %'].iloc[i],color=palette(175),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total B+ %'].iloc[i],width, bottom=b['Total A- %'].iloc[i],color=palette(200),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total A- %'].iloc[i],width, bottom=b['Total A %'].iloc[i],color=palette(225),alpha=alpha)
    plt.bar(ind,b['Total A %'].iloc[i],width,color=palette(255),alpha=alpha)
```

The output image:
[image]

In the first row
**0.0 35.71 0.0 28.57 35.715** 
You can see that the chart did not plot the next 35 because there's a 0.0 between the two numbers. You can observe the same pattern in the remaining rows. I've looked all over the internet, could not find a specific use case such as this. The documentation says that the bottom parameter by default is 0. I do not understand what is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it is likely due to the fact that the bottom needs to be the sum of previous bars. I am trying it out.